# Getting property removed from my land

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, property, trespass

I require somebody else's property to be removed from land I am freeholder of as I need the space myself. I think that:

Them refusing to remove it is "tresspass", a civil wrong.

I can take them to court for it and be awarded compensation for "nuisance".

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you or a previous freeholder give them permission? How long has the stuff been on your property? Is it something like a car that could be moved or is it something fixed to the ground like a fence or a building?

Comment: I did give them permission, but have asked them to remove it at least 10 times over the last 3 months. It requires a truck to remove (see earlier question version of you like).

Comment: I think the previous version of the question is a better question than this one. Details (like who organised the skip and why) are important. It is possible that any case has to be directed against the organiser who refuses to have it removed, not the company who left it there; thus those details are necessary.

Comment: It certainly has more details -- but was not received too well.